# I'm stuck on this angular speed problem :(

Tags: trigonometry, word-problem, ratio

So my professor gave us a bunch of problems to review over the weekend and I was able to do most of them with no problem.  However this problem really confuses me. It's not being graded, but I would love if someone can help me set the problem up into an equation and walk me through it. I just want to learn and understand it more clearly. Thank you very much I truly appreciate it! I'm not very good at the script formatting on this site so I'll include a picture of the problem and a picture of me trying to do it on my notebook.

In an automobile transmission a gear ratio g is the ratio :
$g= \frac{\text{angular speed of engine} }{\text{angular speed of wheels}} $

The angular speed of the engine is shown on the tachometer (in rpm). A certain sports car has wheels with radius 11 in. Its gear ratios are shown in the following table. Suppose the car is in fourth gear and the tachometer reads 3500rpm.

1st gear = ratio 4.1

2nd gear = ratio 3.0

3rd gear = ratio 1.6

4th gear = ratio 0.9

5th gear = ratio 0.7

a) find the angular speed of the engine.

b) find the angular speed of the wheels

c) How fast (in mph) is the car traveling?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have formatted for you.  Please take note for your next question.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are starting out right at least, but I can't read what's written on your paper very easily.  Anyway, as you noted, since the car in in $4$th gear, the gear ratio is $.9,$ and we are told that the angular speed of the engine is 3500 rpm.  Therefore, the angular speed of the wheels is $$\frac{3500}{.9}=3888.889\text{ rpm }$$  The radius of the wheel is $11$ inches so in one revolution it rolls $22\pi$ inches, and in one minute it travels $3888.889\cdot 22\pi$ inches.

Now you just have to convert inches per minute into miles per hour.

Comment: Wait so i have a question.. so the Angular speed of the engine would just be 3500rpm? or would i have to multiple 3500 * 2pi /60?

Comment: i only ask because the other answer submitted suggests that i do the latter and it sort of confused me

Comment: The problem doesn't specify the dimensions for angular speed, so far as I see.  Revolutions per minute seems more natural to me than radians per second in this context, but I can't say for sure.  (I've never heard an engine speed described in anything but revolutions per minute though.)  Ask your teacher what he expects.

Comment: Thanks for your help and clearing that up. You're right, it makes more sense in RPM's and it doesn't specify the dimensions. I'm glad it's alot more simpler than what i made it out to be lol

Answer (score 1):

Angular speed of engine = 3500*2pi/60 rad/sec
Angular speed of wheels = 3500/0.9 * 2pi/60 rad/sec
Speed of car = 3500/0.9 * 2pi * 11/(12*60) * 60/88 mph 
2pi*r/(12*60) converts rpm to fps of the wheels.
60/88 converts fps to mph.